# what's the difference between **/*.java and *.java?

Tags: gradle

this used in gradle task with type copy. the code show as below.

```
task copyTwo(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/test'
    into 'build/anotherDirectory'
    include '**/*.java'
}
```

what is syntax of '**/*'? could I replace it with just one start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `**/` means, that the pattern will include the current directory and any depth of included directories. Since `*` means any file within the current directory only.

As for your case with `**/*.java` and `*.java`. The `*.java` will include only java files in the root directory, but `**/*.java` will include all java files in the root and in any subdirectory

You can read all about it in the [javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html) for PatternFilterable. There this matchers are well described:

> Patterns may include:
>
> ```
> '*' to match any number of characters
> '?' to match any single character
> '**' to match any number of directories or files
> ```